# Very simple problem but yet I can't solve

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm learning the basics of Python and I made this code:

```
alphabet = {a, b, c, d, e}

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

if a + b = c:
  print("right")
else:
  print("wrong")
```

When I run it, the console says:

```
  File "main.py", line 9
    if a + b = c:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'd like to know how to fix that. Thanks in advance for reading this far!

Comment: You have to use `==`.

Comment: Try with `if a + b == c:` This is not your only problem though. What do you want to achieve with this `alphabet = {a, b, c, d, e}` ?

Comment: @dimitar.d Thanks for answering. Actually, the first line has no use. Maybe I will erase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a second `=` equals sign. In Python (and most other programming languages), a single `=` is for *assignment*, or setting the value of something, while `==` is for checking *equality*, like what you want to do here. ([Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp))

```py
if a + b == c:
  print("right")
else:
  print("wrong")
```